# Change R default path (.libPaths) in sage

Tags: r, startup, sage

I want to use the same directory for my addon R-packages that I use in standalone R. The following works from within sage:

```
r(".libPaths('/home/USERNAME/R/my-libraries')")
```

But when I include this line in `~/.sage/sagerc` or `~/.sage/sage.init` it doesn't work. Is there a file in the `/opt/sage/` - tree where I can configure this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper place to do this is `~/.sage/init.sage`.  Or was that a typo?  (In which case I'm really surprised it works in Sage but not there.)

Comment: oops, you're right - works. Being able to read is a great advantage …
Thank you.